# Has anybody who started with the Dark Side switched to the Light Side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Of course Darth Vader seems to embrace the Light Side just before his death, but he also began his training on the Light Side under Qui-Gonn and Obi-Wan. Kylo Ren also admits to "struggling" with the Light Side, but he was

> trained by Luke Skywalker.

So we see that some Jedi go over to the Dark Side (Count Dooku is an example where there is no apparent "regret"). Are there any examples of Force users who begin with the Dark Side but embrace the Light Side? If not, why do all the defections seem to go one way?

Comment: Do you want new canon or legends as well?

Comment: @Ancalagon I'm not enough of an expert to know the difference.